# Is there a way to align div elements in rows to be in a specific column using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for the first time. Im just finishing up this form, but I want to add a button at the bottom right of form. I've got the button where I want it to be vertically, but right now its at the bottom left of my form, not the right. The only solution I could find is to add 3 empty divs, and then my button as the fourth div. This causes it to be in the 4th column. I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this without using unnecesarry code.

*Im fairly new to stackoverflow, I apologize if my question is missing something or isn't clear*

Here's my code for that row so far:

Note: parent row is defined using col-md-12.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 3px">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.WETSubmitButton(btnAdd, new { @class = "btn btn-default", name = "action", value = "Add" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think bootstrap has an `offset` helper class somewhere but you *could* make the left column `col-md-9` rather than 3 lots of 3....right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would just use the offset class like this:

```
<div class="row pt-1" >
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-9">
        @Html.WETSubmitButton(btnAdd, new { @class = "btn btn-default", name = "action", value = "Add" })
    </div>
</div>
```

also I removed your padding and used the bootstrap built in padding class on the row.